# how to lose the focus of JtextFeild onClick

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

how to lose focus of JFormatedTextfeild when click on Calender Window

```
private void dateTxtFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    PickDate ex=new PickDate();       
    // dateTxt.setText(Helper.pickDate.toString());
}

...

private class MyDateListener implements DateListener
{
    public void dateChanged(DateEvent e)
    {
        Calendar c = e.getSelectedDate();
        if (c != null) {        
            formatTxt.setText(c.getTime()); 
            PickDate.this.dispose(); // pickdate is nothing but JFrame in which calender shows 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No time selected.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may request focus on any other component because as you know a window can contain one focused element at a time.

    AnyOtherSwingComponent.requestFocusInWindow();

Comment: sorry but I couldn't understand

Answer (score 2):

One hack I have used in the past is to toggle the focusability of the component. In your onClick event:

```
//we just want to lose current caret focus
//but still have textfield be focusable
dateTxt.setFocusable(false);
dateTxt.setFocusable(true);
```